# Delete Button Not Appearing in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

In my program, I am trying to implement the swipe to delete feature on UITableViewCells but the delete button is not appearing even though the cell does move as it should when swiping. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as resultsCell

    otherName = cell.usernameLbl.text!
    otherProfileName = cell.profileNameLbl.text!
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToConversationVC", sender: self)

}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return resultsUsernameArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:resultsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as resultsCell

    cell.usernameLbl.text = self.resultsUsernameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.profileNameLbl.text =       self.resultsProfileNameArray[indexPath.row]

    resultsImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (imageData: NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.profileImg.image = image

        }
    }

    return cell

}


@IBAction func logoutBtn_click(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

// called when a row is moved
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,
    toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // remove the dragged row's model
        let val = friends.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)

        // insert it into the new position
        friends.insert(val, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .Delete:
            // remove the deleted item from the model
            friends.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            // remove the deleted item from the `UITableView`
            resultsTable.editing = resultsTable.editing
            resultsTable.editing =  true

            self.resultsTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        default:
            return
        }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    return .Delete

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableView is too big hence the delete button is out of the screen